How to set normal and bold font-weight independantly with CSS?
I have a font with three weights: light, regular, bold. I would like to use light-weight for normal text and bold-weight for bold text.
Using font-weight: lighter doesn't work in this case because it forces bold text to regular-weight, thus breaking bold functionality.
What is the correct CSS to achieve this?


<html>
<style>
p {
  font-weight: lighter;
}
</style>
<body>
<p>Light weight, <b>bold weight</b></p>
</body>
</html>




it forces bold text to regular-weight, thus breaking bold functionality --> no it doesn't

Unless I'm missing something, the above code causes all text to be shifted to the next lighter font weight. In my case, with only three distinct font weights, this means bold uses the regular weight and normal text uses the light weight.

b has font-weight: bold; by default so the font-weight you apply to p doesn't really matter (unless you have more code you need to show us)

Interesting, that is not the behaviour I'm seeing. This is my complete code and I do not get any bold text. Removing the CSS restores bold but does not use light-weight for normal text.

@telenachos - It's complicated. Browsers do different things. Some browsers default b elements to font-weight:bolder, others default it to font-weight:bold. With your example, in the former browsers, the b element's used font weight gets reduced to normal, in the latter browsers it remains as bold.

@PoulBak there is no inheritance when you set font-weight on p and there is a default one set on b. The one on b (defined by the browser) will always be considered

@PoulBak https://i.sstatic.net/pB6teObf.png I still insist that there is no inheritance here because a default font-weight is applied on the b element. Test yourself and inspect the code to see "no inheritance"

@TemaniAfif: I'm sorry, you are right (why didn't I just run the code snippet)?

@TemaniAfif - It's definitely tricky here The CSS Fonts Level 4 spec says for font-weight:bolder - "The computed weight is calculated based on the inherited font-weight value using the chart below.. Firefox defaults b elements to font-weight:bolder and the HTML spec rendering section says that is the expected behaviour, although Chromium is not compliant. Personally, I think the use of "inherited" there is unfortunate. It's not doing what we normally think of as inheritance.

CSS:
p {font-weight: lighter;}
b, strong {font-weight: bold;}


You may also re-map your fonts to the desired default font-weights by custom @font-face rules:


/* map light (300) to regular (400) */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v21/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLDz8Z1xlFQ.woff2) format('woff2');
}

/* heavy (800) to bold (700) */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v21/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLDD4Z1xlFQ.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins';
}
<p>Light weight, <b>bold weight</b></p>
<p>Light weight, <strong>bold weight</strong></p>



In the above example we map the actual Poppins light/300 to regular/400. You can extend this concept e.g to tweak the default weight for (by default) boldened elements like <strong> or headings like <h1-5> (e.g. if you think the default bold weight is too thick or too thin).
Besides, I recommend to avoid relative font-weights like lighter or bolder as they are not very intuitive (See mdn docs: "Meaning of relative weights"). Related post "Bolding text is not working in different devices"
